# Copper Plane Oz and Max Amp Relationship

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, motor-controller, lipo, high-current

I am attempting to design a power distribution board for up to four ESC controllers that can draw a continuous current of 40 A per ESC (so 160 A), from one LiPo battery. Additionally this board will power a control board that will draw approximately 50 W max.

My biggest questions revolve around determining the copper pour for the power plane that can support this large current draw. I know this level of current draw is doable for a cheap price as the HolyBro PixHawk 4 Power board is relatively small and claims to be able to supply 120 A to ESC controllers.

- How do you dictate the copper oz pour/width that would meet a high amp requirement?
- Is there a rule of thumb between the copper oz used and the max amperage for a board width? Or is this an experimental finding

Thanks in advance for any direction on this subject.

Comment: What kind of distances, or trace lengths are you talking about?  And what kind of voltage drop can you tolerate?  Temperature rise of the conductor is just one of several things you should be addressing.

Comment: Hello SteveSh, the trace lengths will be 50mm (2 inch max) from battery connector through shunt resistor, to the plane providing power to the ESC controllers and the connector to the IO board. I was wondering if I could get away with just a high weight "power plane" to be responsible for providing the current draw

Comment: No rule of thumb. You need to consider trace width and length and copper thickness. Another technique for adding copper to the board is to just use a bus bar or even solder down a solid copper wire for a little extra ampacity.

Comment: Make sure you calculate your shunt resistor power dissipation and choose a suitably rated part. At these current levels it is easy to blow a shunt. Once the shunt opens, the current sense amplifier will be destroyed pretty much immediately. Maybe other stuff, too.

Comment: mKeith, would you do the 80% rule for the shunt wattage rating? I.e. if I'm dumping 8W dissipation across the shunt, then have a it rated for 10W?

Comment: I would study the datasheet for the shunt carefully, and maybe take some measurements. They need to be de-rated if the board runs hot (which yours might). Often, 50% is a better rule. In other words, if your dissipation is 0.5W, get a 1W resistor. If you are dumping 8W, keep in mind that the whole area around the shunt is going to get very hot. 8 Watts is a lot of heat to get rid of without a fan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you dictate the copper oz pour/width that would meet a high amp
> requirement?

It really depends on how much heating your design can tolerate and what temperature the designs "ambient" temperature will be. There are dozens of calculators ([this](https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html) being one of them) that can help you calculate the temperature rise. With at 40C rise and 40A that would be about 400mils at 2oz copper, quite a large trace! (per one channel). So then your options are to go to a higher oz copper weight, doubling the weight will half the trace width but will also add expense (4oz+) being a non standard copper weight for most fabricators.

Also 60C would be ~300mil so you could just say the design needs to tolerate a higher temp.

Other options include using multiple 1oz layers in a 4+ layer design.

Also, connector resistance and heating will be a concern for a high current design such as this one.

> Is there a rule of thumb between the copper oz used and the max
> amperage for a board width? Or is this an experimental finding

It's not experimental, it's simply resistance, and resistance generating heat, and how much heat can move to ambient through the silkscreen. Keep in mind that connectors and components will change how much heat leaves the heated copper trace, there aren't good ways to find out where the heat will go outside of a thermal FEM (Finite Element Method) simulation.

Comment: I believe this closest answers my question, thank you. I saw that a lot of those online calculators based off of IPC-2221 which is only up to 30A. Do you think a large copper pour for the power plane would be sufficient to drive the ESCs? The board will have very few components, I just want to provide a mechanism to transfer the battery power to 4 ESC controllers, and a separate controller board.

Comment: 30A plus is uncommon. As long as you provide a low resistance pathway that doesn't overheat, it doesn't matter what you use, as a designer you need to understand that everything has resistance and at 10A's it needs to be accounted for.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer Voltage Spike. When you design high current designs, do you use any equations to find necessary tolerances/estimates for resistance induced by the copper pour? I saw that you were taking into account the temperature rise. Is 40C a tolerable temp increase for high power boards? Thanks again for all your help. Edit -- Would you recommend any books to learn more about power pcb design, or is this topic burn to learn?

Comment: The temperature rise will depend on what else you have on the board (components have ratings and so does the PCB depending on the material you get those ratings should not be exceeded, plus if you get too hot, you melt solder/components right off the board which is not fun), in most of my designs I can't tolerate a lot of temperature dissipated in the board for other reasons. Most of the info can be found on the internet on how to size traces, saturn pcb calculator is a good tool

Comment: Sorry, I should have known that

Answer (score 1):

For cost reasons you don’t choose a high oz Cu board then etch away most of the Cu that you paid dearly for.  You choose the wire gauge needed by the area and length for minimal Voltage drop and inductance by using jumpers, busbars similar with Litz wire for cables or twisted pairs.

Next question?

Comment: Hello Tony, thanks for the answer. I meant more of a copper pour for a power plane. All the previous boards I've built I've used power/gnd planes in a 4 layer orientation and its worked fine. In this case, with the higher amp requirement, I was wondering the relationship between the copper weight and the max current that could be supplied.

Comment: Saturn PCB design exe computes temp rise for surface tracks of any weight, width, I guess assumptions are convection cooled not enclosed

Comment: Thank you for the pointer Tony! I wasn't aware of Saturn PCB design. Thanks for mentioning it.